# can I change Os profile in existing virtual machine using azure vm rest api (PUT)?

Tags: azure, migration, virtual-machine, azure-functions, azure-rest-api

Try to update OsProfile after Virtual Machine is migrated from on premise to azure cloud because I need to install provisionVMAgent under osProfile ?
Using this API Version-

Reference Url for APi -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/createorupdate#request-body

PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}?api-version=2019-03-01

```
{
  "location": "westus",
  "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "Standard_D1_v2"
    },
    "storageProfile": {
      "osDisk": {
        "name": "myVMosdisk",
        "image": {
          "uri": "http://{existing-storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{existing-container-name}/{existing-generalized-os-image-blob-name}.vhd"
        },
        "osType": "Windows",
        "createOption": "FromImage",
        "caching": "ReadWrite",
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "http://{existing-storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{existing-container-name}/myDisk.vhd"
        }
      }
    },
    "osProfile": {
      "adminUsername": "{your-username}",
      "computerName": "myVM",
      "adminPassword": "{your-password}"
    },
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "id": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/{existing-nic-name}",
          "properties": {
            "primary": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Response In Postman -

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",
    "message": "Changing property 'osProfile' is not allowed.",
    "target": "osProfile"
}
```

Is This Possible to update Os Profile after Vm migration ?  Or
Can I install provisionVMAgent in virtual machine after migration of VM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see `provisionVMAgent` working at the VM provision time from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/createorupdate#windowsconfiguration), So it's not possible to update it after VM has created.
[image]

In this case, when you have [created a custom-image VM from an unmanaged generalized os image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/createorupdate#create-a-custom-image-vm-from-an-unmanaged-generalized-os-image.), you could [manually install the Windows VM Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows#manual-installation). The VM Agent is supported on Windows Server 2008 R2 and later.

The VM Agent can be installed by double-clicking the Windows installer file. For an automated or unattended installation of the VM agent, run the following command:

```
msiexec.exe /i WindowsAzureVmAgent.2.7.1198.778.rd_art_stable.160617-1120.fre /quiet
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks Nancy for reply, where this command will be executed ?

Comment: It will be executed on your existing Azure VM via RDP to that VM. After that, you can [detect that agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows#detect-the-vm-agent), Alternatively, you can [install the VM agent for an offline windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/install-vm-agent-offline).